# mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un buscador para mi aplicativo web, a la hora de incluir las consultas a la base de datos me sale el siguiente error `mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given`.
Utilice las siguientes líneas de código para que me mostraran mas detalladamente el error pero no pude encontrar una solución

```
if(!$fila){
  var_dump(mysqli_error($conexion));
  exit;
}
```

Y esta es la advertencia que me sale al ejecutarlo: `string(158) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 3' at line 7"`

Dejo el código, agradecería mucho la ayuda.

```
<?php
       //PAGINADOR//
     $sql_registe = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT COUNT(*) as total_registro FROM usuario WHERE (id 
       LIKE '%busqueda%' OR
       username LIKE '%busqueda%' OR email LIKE '%busqueda%' OR role LIKE '%busqueda%')");
      $result_register = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_registe);
      $total_registro = $result_register['total_registro'];
       $por_pagina = 3;
       if(empty($_GET['pagina'])){
       $pagina = 1;
       }else{

      $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
    
       }
        $empieza = ($pagina-1) * $por_pagina;
      $total_paginas=ceil($total_registro / $por_pagina);

     $query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT usuario.id, usuario.username, usuario.email, 
      usuario.password, usuario.role, tipodocumento.TipoDocumento, estado.Estado, curso.Curso FROM 
     usuario 
     INNER JOIN tipodocumento ON usuario.ID_TipoDocumento = TipoDocumento.IDTipoDocumento

      INNER JOIN estado ON usuario.ID_Estado = Estado.IDEstado

     INNER JOIN curso ON usuario.ID_Curso = Curso.IDCurso 
       WHERE (usuario.id LIKE '%busqueda%' OR usuario.username LIKE '%busqueda%' OR usuario.email LIKE 
     '%busqueda%'
    OR usuario.role LIKE '%busqueda%' OR tipodocumento.TipoDocumento LIKE '%busqueda%' OR estado.Estado 
       LIKE '%busqueda%'
       OR curso.Curso LIKE '%busqueda%') AND LIMIT $empieza, $por_pagina");
     //////////BUSCADOR//////////
      ?>

        <form action="buscar_usuario.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="busqueda" id="busqueda" placeholder="Buscar.."><br>
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Buscar">
    </form>
    <br><br>
    <center>
     <table width="1016" border="1" class="tabladelista">
    <tr>
      <th width="126" scope="col">CODIGO</th>
      <th width="456" scope="col">NOMBRE</th>
      <th width="119" scope="col">EMAIL</th>
      <th width="119" scope="col">PASSWORD</th>
      <th width="119" scope="col">ROL</th>
      <th width="119" scope="col">TIPO DOCUMENTO</th>
      <th width="119" scope="col">ESTADO</th>
      <th width="119" scope="col">CURSO</th>
      <th width="145" scope="col">ELIMINAR</th>
      <th width="136" scope="col">MODIFICAR</th>
    </tr>   
    <?php            
      while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
  
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $fila['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila['username']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila['email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila['password']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila['role']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila['TipoDocumento']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila['Estado']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila['Curso']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="usuario_eliminar.php?cod=<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>">Eliminar</a></td>        
        <td><a href="frmusuario_modificar.php?cod_producto=<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>">Modificar</a></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Hola, no puedes utilizar LIMIT en una condición (WHERE ... AND LIMIT ...) ya que LIMIT es para delimitar los registros que quieres sacar. Si lo que quieres es listarlos quitale el AND antes del LIMIT y lo pruebas a ver que tal te va. Saludos

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, al quitarle el AND ya no me sale ningún error, pero me sigue sin traer los registros de la base de datos

Comment: No quiero desanimarte, pero tu código necesita ser repensado muy seriamente. Por ejemplo, ¿por qué ejecutas tres consultas cuando podrías obtener los datos que necesitas en una sola consulta, uniendo las tablas? Si te parece demasiado ahora (aunque más tarde es probable que tengas que pensar en optimizar, cuando las tablas crezcan y el programa empiece a ser lento) puedes depurar tu código actual para hacerlo funcionar. Para ello puedes imprimir las consultas que se están produciendo, revisarlas y tratar de ejecutarlas directamente en la base de datos y ver si traen algo.